# Visual Studio Code for MacOS freezes on using map/set in C++

Tags: c++, macos, dictionary, debugging, visual-studio-code

I was debugging my big C++ project and VS Code would freeze everytime. On close look I figured that this happens in a simple hello world program if I just include a map/set variable in my code. This is very similar to issue described in below bug:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5805

I am using VS Code for MacOS version - May 2021 (version 1.57) and C++ Std 11.

Any workaround / solution would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!
Peace.

Comment: This is clearly a bug in the debugger itself, so why ask for help with it? Only Microsoft can fix it.

Comment: Microsoft seems to still be having problems with both vscode and Visual Studio on the Mac. In case anyone is looking for a solution I'm not sure there is one yet? There are a number of open bugs relating to this problem on Github i.e. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/7240

Comment: LLDB debugger hangs (using 100% cpu) at launch if std::map is uninitialised: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5805